# Result value of C# GetStringAsync() becomes null when passed by parameter

Tags: c#, .net

In a .Net Standard 2.0 library, used at this moment in an android app, my method receives a string from GetStringAsync() correctly. However, when I pass this value to another method, the value becomes null.

At the first debugger point, the value of "data" string is correct:

[image]

But inside a method, the value is now null:

[image]

Do you know what happened with this `string`?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Be sure to include the code as **text** rather than images.

Comment: Is it possible that multiple threads are executing at once, such the the **first** `data` you see is from a different thread to the **second** (i.e. `Check` is being called twice at the same time)?

Comment: It is not clear what "But inside a method," means, or how the value is passed. Post code as text, preferably a mcve.

Comment: When you are in the Check method where the debugger shows `json` is null, click the Stack window and go back a stackframe until you're in the context where `Check` was called. Examine the state there.

Comment: Yes, can you check CallStack and verify what method called `Check`. Strings are immutable, so there should not be any magic

Comment: I found the problem. It's a compiler bug. Please don't downvote a question if you don't know anything about the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem. There's is a bug in this c# for android version. If I change the method to Check(string, string) and pass the parameter two times, the first parameter receives the correct value and the second will be null. This answer will be important if someone has the same problem.

Comment: Consider the difference between a function and a value. If you roll a dice twice, you'll likely get 2 different results, and no one would accuse the dice of being 'bugged' ;)